# NoMethodError in will paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have written this in my controller:

```
 def index
    @invoices = Invoice.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3)
    @invoices = Invoice.all(:select=>"invoices.id, invoices.invoice_name, 
                                     invoices.invoice_number, invoices.invoice_date,
                                     invoices.invoice_sent, invoices.current_eta, 
                                     invoices.invoice_status, invoices.invoice_amount, 
                                     projects.project_name, clients.client_name, 
                                     companies.company_name, currencies.symbol as invoice_symbol", 

    :joins => "left outer join projects on invoices.project_id = projects.id
               left outer join clients on projects.client_id = projects.id
               left outer join currencies on currencies.id = projects.currency_id
               left outer join companies on clients.company_id = companies.id",
    :order =>"invoice_name desc")

    if @invoices.blank?
      flash[:notice] = "There are no Invoices defined. You can create them by clicking 'New Invoice'"
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @invoices }
    end
  end
```

In my views file I have writte this:

```
  <div class="digg_pagination">
    <div clas="page_info">
      <%= page_entries_info @invoices %>
    </div>
    <%= will_paginate @invoices, :container => false %>
  </div>
```

But I am getting this error:

```
NoMethodError in Invoices#index

Showing /home/icicle/work/code/invoiced/app/views/invoices/_list.html.erb where line #59 raised:

undefined method `total_pages' for #<Array:0xbdfb708>

Extracted source (around line #59):

56: </table>
57:   <div class="digg_pagination">
58:     <div clas="page_info">
59:       <%= page_entries_info @invoices %>
60:     </div>
61:     <%= will_paginate @invoices, :container => false %>
62:   </div>
```

I also tried to change the version of will_paginate gem but still I am getting the same error. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either rename the 2nd instance variable or instead of all please use paginate

```
    @invoices = Invoice.paginate(:select=>"invoices.id, invoices.invoice_name, 
                                 invoices.invoice_number, invoices.invoice_date,
                                 invoices.invoice_sent, invoices.current_eta, 
                                 invoices.invoice_status, invoices.invoice_amount, 
                                 projects.project_name, clients.client_name, 
                                 companies.company_name, currencies.symbol as invoice_symbol", 

:joins => "left outer join projects on invoices.project_id = projects.id
           left outer join clients on projects.client_id = projects.id
           left outer join currencies on currencies.id = projects.currency_id
           left outer join companies on clients.company_id = companies.id",
:order =>"invoice_name desc",:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3)
```

Comment: I solved the issue by writing this: @invoices = Invoice.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3).all(:select=> "  ", :joins => "  ", :order => " "). And thanks for your suggestion